# Animating while loop using @animate macro

Tags: julia, plots.jl

Is it possible to use the @animate macro with while loops?

Documentation here in the case of for loops: https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/animations/

Comment: You should really check this by yourself and discover the answer, it would be faster than posting the question. Anyway, you may want to use `@macroexpand` (on a working example) to see the what the `@animate` macro is doing under the hood.

Comment: I tried using the documentation for a for loop by analogy and it didn't work, but I thought maybe I wasn't doing it right. Thanks for the suggestion, I will explore it using `@macroexpand`.